# Can i create a custom permission level which allow users to ONLY create an item inside cusotm list. but they can not view,search,edit,delete items

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, custom-permission-level

I have a custom list inside our sharepoint online team site. and the team site have the publishing features enabled. the custom list is being used to submit users' feedback. **So i want to create a custom permission level, which allow users to create new items, but they can not edit, view or search the item after being submitted.**

so i checked the built-in permission levels, and i can not find any one which support this operation.. so can i using remote power-shell to create such a custom permission level?

now i am already aware of the "Item-level Permissions" setting inside the cusotm list, but this will work in preventing users from seeing other items. but i even do not want users to be able to view or edit their own items after submitting it..

Regards

Answer (score 1):

*Update: I am using SP 2013 and used a 2010 workflow for my solution*

Save a template of your existing list to create a new list from the template.  Use Sharepoint designer to copy over all of the relevant columns to your new list.  Once the new item has been created in `List B`, make the workflow delete the item from `List A`.

I did something like this for reporting health & safety concerns - users can create new items in `List A`.  But it's a 'fire & forget', since once it is submitted all users (including the user that created it) can not see it since the workflow deletes it.

The workflow will need to run with an impersonation step (rather like elevated permissions to run as Workflow author, if memory serves correct), since users will have no access at all to `List B`.  If you don't use an impersonation step  the workflow will show an error - since users do not have permission to create items there.

Here's a picture to illustrate it:
[image]

You'll need to select your own list of course, then match up the field to the value, with value coming from the current item in `List A`.

The Email line is just to reply to the submitter that their item was successfully created (on List B, though they don't need to know that) + thanks for submitting etc.  Since on `List A`, it gets deleted pretty much as soon as it is created.

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i am using SP online. also i am looking to fix this with a simpler approach by using cusotm permision levels

Comment: I very much doubt that you can avoid a solution like Tallys. However I would recommend making a proof of concept in Flow

Comment: @KasperBoLarsen i also think that implementing this in a workflow is not the right appraoch ... i find this link which talks about creating a submit only permission level https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/add-only-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010/ .. i am currently testing it on SP online and seems the results are promising..

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to create a custom permission level, which allow users to create new items, but they can not edit, view or search the item after being submitted.

You can do as Tally said, create impersonation step workflow to created list item in an list which you have no permissions on.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i think it is possible to define a submit only permsion level, as mentioned in this link https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/add-only-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010/ .. i am testing it on SP online as seems the results are promising